# ActiveAdmin pulling up wrong record by id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Here's one I just can't get to the bottom of:

I'm using ActiveAdmin and I've got a tab for users (powered by Devise).  For the longest time everything worked perfectly.  Then today I went to view one of the users and noticed that for some reason, it pulled up MY user account instead of the user's that I had clicked on.  I tried the show page as well with the same result.  It does this for all users.  I have no idea when this started... prior to today I hadn't clicked on either of these actions in quite some time... at least several weeks.  But the point is I must have done *something*, and now I can't see any users besides myself.

I checked the logs after visiting /admin/users/153 and saw:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"153"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  AdminUser Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
```

It's selecting my user id (2) instead of the one in the params hash (153).  I haven't modified anything in ActiveAdmin, and to the best of my knowledge, I'm not using anything that would interfere with it... so I'm stumped.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps there's an error in your code somewhere... Please show your controller code, your view code and your routes.

Comment: Well that's the thing... I'm using Active Admin on my User model, and my user model is provided by Devise, therefor I have no users controller outside of the one provided by Devise.  Similarly, my views are provided by Active Admin.  I haven't customized either Devise or Active Admin.  So there's nothing really for me to post....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure my answer will help you but I faced a similar issue. In my case, I set @challenge in application_controller where I can use from anywhere in any controller. The problem arose when I edited a Challenge record by Active admin, it updated the @challenge I set earlier. It took me couple hours to figure this out and it turned out to be just because sharing class variable.